# Non-blocking asynchronous Jersey JAX-RS with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs, completable-future

I'm studying Jersey and I saw in a book you can use CompletableFuture (and CompletitionStage) in order to call your API in a NON-Blocking IO way.

But when I call the API with Postman, I always get 500.

If I debug the code I see that the methods are invoked correctly.

The first GET method is synchronous and works correcly.
The second and the third return **error 500**.

What am i missing?

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloController {

  @GET
  @Path("/first")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String first() {
    return "It works";
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/second")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public CompletionStage<Response> second() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Response.accepted().entity("Hello!").build());
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/third")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public CompletableFuture<Response> third() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Response.accepted().entity("Hello!").build());
  }
}
```

Comment: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html

Comment: may you answer with this comment, so I can assign your answer as the right one. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexMawashi If you have it sort it out, you can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Your approach is correct, it's an alternative to `@Suspended`.  You just needed to 1)  kicked off a thread to execute the logic and called `complete` on the `CompletableFuture`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to create an async endpoint with Jersey:

```
@POST
@Path("/goes")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public void createTodoAsync3(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, Todo todo) {

    CompletableFuture<Response> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> createTodo3(todo));
    future.thenAccept(resp -> asyncResponse.resume(resp));
}
private Response createTodo3(Todo todo) {
    //all logic goes here
    return Response.accepted().entity(todo).build();
}
```